# HTML Custom attributes compatibility with mobile devices?

Tags: browser, custom-attributes, smartphone, html

Does anyone know if I could use custom HTML attributes in a Web Page, most of mobile devices could read it? or some devices will omit attributes as a default way? In other words: Most default web-browsers installed into mobile devices has the ability to process custom attributes?

I have some code like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" value="0" percent="50" idColor="12">
```

Answer (score 1):

the items you are talking about are attributes.  If the webbrowser doesn't understand a particular attribute it *should* ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers generally treat unknown attributes as properties assigned to elements, without any default impact, but recognized as attributes in CSS and JavaScript. In your case, for example, the CSS selector `input[idColor]` would match those `input` elements that have the attribute `idColor`, even though such an attribute is not defined in HTML specs.

In JavaScript, however, they are normally not available directly as properties, so e.g. `document.getElementById('txt1').percent` would yield `undefined`, though there are browser differences. But `document.getElementById('txt1').getAttribute('percent')` would yield `50`.

I would expect this to apply to mobile browsers, too, though I only tested this on Android.

It is however unsafe to make up your own attribute names in HTML. What happens if some future HTML spec, or just some browser, assigns a meaning to an attribute called `percent`? The meaning could be quite surprising, for all that we can now.

Therefore the recommended way to use attributes that carry arbitrary data for use in client side scripting is to use [names that start with `data-`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes). This gives you your own naming space to play with. No reasonable browser or search engine will ever treat such attributes as anything but page author’s private playground, not to be messed up with. So it would be better to use e.g. `data-percent="50" data-color="12"`.